# Are there any way to control jquery ajax call speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website which will send a lot api request to backend api when the page is loaded. I realized it is not a good idea to send all the api request in parallel at once. So my question is:
Are there any easy to use configuration for jquery Ajax to control api request sending speed, such as two at a time or one at a time.
Thanks
Frank

Comment: `AJAX` is a `Promise`, you can deal with it in `.then` method..

Comment: No, there is no such configuration for this. You can of course use logic to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

To do each request immediately after the previous one completes (one at a time), simply chain them:

```
let numThings = 10;

function getThing() {
    $.get("url").then(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
        numThings--;
        if (numThings > 0) { getThing(); }
    });
}

getThing();
```

If the requests are to different URLs, or you want different requests to the same URL:

```
function getFirstThing() {
    $.get("url").then(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
        getSecondThing();
    });
}

function getSecondThing() {
    $.get("url").then(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
        getThirdThing();
    });
}
...

getFirstThing();
```

You could write it more tersely this way:

```
$.get("url").then(response => { 
    console.log(response);
    $.get("url").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

If that's too fast or you want to space them on a set interval, just use `setTimeout`:

```
function getFirstThing() {
    $.get("url").then(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
    });
}

function getSecondThing() {
    $.get("url").then(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
    });
}

getFirstThing();
setTimeout(getSecondThing, 1000);
```

Note that I'm using the `$.get` shorthand here, but you can use `$.ajax` the same way if you need it.